# Bootstrap layout - responsive rows and columns order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling right now with the order of the columns and rows of a bootstrap layout and I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible using bootrsap's rows/columns grid system.

So, I have the following layout for large devices:

[image]

And I want the columns to be reoredered on small devices like this:

[image]

Problem is... I have this "column 2" and I can't break it in two parts :D

Is there another way to achieve the same kind of layot using bootstrap?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

So, the large devices layout would be something like the this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div>
        Imagine a big data table here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          Columns inside row 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See it on codepen: https://codepen.io/lucas-labs/pen/yLLeVxO

Comment: can you give the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the column order, the columns must share the same parent. The only way to get this to work in Bootstrap 4 would be to disable the flexbox on `lg` and use floats.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mainrow d-lg-block d-flex overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 first-column float-left">
            <div class="big-data-table">
                Imagine a big data table here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 second-column float-right order-first">
            <div class="row myrow">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 second-column float-right">
            <div class="row myrow">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    Columns inside row 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/V9eB4jUNhw